# Primitive function in JAVA

Tags: java

Is it possible to write primitive function in [java](/questions/tagged/java)?
Something like this:

```
void x() {
    System.out.printf("ok");
}
```

Like this in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

```
function x() {
    console.log('ok');
}
```

Comment: You mean a standalone function, as opposed to a method?

Comment: Add `static` to it? Or do you mean lambdas?

Comment: @khelwood yes, function without class.

Comment: Not really. You can put a static method inside a class. Or you can assign a lambda function to a local variable or a field. But it's still inside a class. Pretty much everything in Java is inside a class.

Comment: @dan1st `static void x() { ...` -> `error: class, interface, or enum expected`

Comment: What is your usecase, never had one so i am wondering, what you are doing. You need atleast a main class, inside of it you have then your main method and probably some more methods

Comment: Each method needs to be defined in a class but methods can live without instances if they are `static`. What you want breaks the OOP concept of java.